# How do I protect a Google sheet but allow users to use the pivot table?

Tags: google-sheets

I wish to have a protected google sheet that only I can edit but viewers can still expand a pivot table.  Most ideally, I would like to be able to publish the pivot table to the web and viewers be able to expand the table. What are my options, if any?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible on Google Sheets. One of your options is to use Google Data Studio or another similar app.